# How to colorize text and background of a Imagick caption via PHP

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to convert this Imagick shell command:

```sh
convert -geometry 200x -quiet -background "#0003" -fill "#ffff" -size 200x35 -gravity center caption:"12:50" image-20171214165000.JPG +swap -gravity north -composite image-20171214165000-thumb.JPG 2>&1
```

to work with PHP Imagick plugin, but I am having trouble with caption fill color.

The above shell command produces this (expected) output:

[image]

Yet, my current PHP approach:

```php
<?php

$time = "12:50";
$img = new \Imagick();
$img->readImage('image-20171214165000.JPG');
$img->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);

$imageprops = $img->getImageGeometry();
$width = $imageprops['width'];
$height = $imageprops['height'];
$img = $img->transformImage($width . "x" . $height, "200x");

$capt = new \Imagick();
$capt->setBackgroundColor("rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)");
$capt->setGravity(\Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$capt->newPseudoImage(200, 35, "Caption:" . $time);
// $opacityColor = new \ImagickPixel("rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)");
// $capt->colorizeImage("rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)", $opacityColor);

$img->setGravity(\Imagick::GRAVITY_NORTH);
$img->compositeImage($capt, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
$capt->destroy();

$img->stripImage();
$img->writeImage('image-20171214165000-thumb.JPG');
$img->destroy();

?>
```

produces the output with black text:

[image]

When using the commented-out `colorizeImage()` function, the text ("12:50") is produced as white, but that also whitens the background of the caption (which is unwanted).

How can I set the color of the caption background (`rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)`) and of the caption text (`rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)`) without them affecting each other?

Comment: Is this answer helping in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40682275/594138 ?

Comment: @TomRegner, unfortunately not as I have tried that already.

Answer (score 1):

Approach (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/10760237/451962) that satisfies my criteria is the following:

```php
<?php

$time = "12:50";
$img = new \Imagick();
$img->readImage('image-20171214165000.JPG');
$img->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);

$imageprops = $img->getImageGeometry();
$width = $imageprops['width'];
$height = $imageprops['height'];
$img = $img->transformImage($width . "x" . $height, "200x");

$capt = new \Imagick();
$draw = new \ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFontSize(32);
$fillcolor = new \ImagickPixel("white");
$draw->setFillColor($fillcolor);
$draw->setGravity(\Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$bgcolor = new \ImagickPixel("rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)");
$capt->newImage('200', '35', $bgcolor);
$capt->annotateImage($draw, 0, 0, 0, $time);

$img->setGravity(\Imagick::GRAVITY_NORTH);
$img->compositeImage($capt, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
$img->writeImage('image-20171214165000-thumb.JPG');

?>
```